# How to display custom post type using Divi?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, divi

I am trying to build a school website using Divi builder, and I need custom content to display like teachers, subjects etc. I used Custom Post Type UI and ACF plugin to create custom fields and I used the Divi theme builder to display dynamic content, I looked up tutorials and followed the process step by step, I added a title and an image but nothing is displayed in the page when I exit the builder. Can anyone help me please
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you see your custom fields among the dynamic fields?  You should try changing the template and choose to display it for the archive page of your custom post type or for the single page of your custom post type and not just any page.  Remember to save the template at the top left right on the page of the photo you sent, it's trivial but very often we forget

Comment: Hi, there's no archive page for custom post types, and I think the template should be on the page you want to display the content on, I tried single page and even when custom fields are among dynamic fields, nothing is displayed.

Comment: This should also work for custom post types, or you could try creating a generic archive for post types.  When you created the custom post type did you enable the archive?  What type of content do your fields have (text, images)?.  could you insert other photos of the list of templates in the generator and then the custom fields?